# How to call and use items from an ArrayList in another class using the index values

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

In this program I am to create an employee roster. For this I had to create multiple ArrayLists which you will see in my code. My first class "EmployeeRoster" holds the first and last names, Tax ID's , and hourly wage. Inputting all of this is fine and dandy in this class. However, in my "Employee_Payment" class I need to prompt the user to input first the employee's number, or the number that it is in the ArrayList. The program should then know that which first and last name it needs reference so that the user can input the week and hours they worked during the week. I'm having issues with calling the ArrayLists over. I've tried things I found online and I either get nothing or a blank array. I want to be able to input an index value so that that the user or I can input the hours that certain employee worked. I hope I described clearly enough. Thanks!

EmployeeRoster Class:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class EmployeeRoster {

    String firstName =" ";
    String lastName = " ";
    String tid =" ";
    double wage = 0; 
ArrayList<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> tax = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Double> hw = new ArrayList<>();



public void  Roster()
{
  Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);  

  while(!firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
  {
    System.out.println("Enter employee record information."); 
    firstName = n.next();
    if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
    {
        break;
    }
    lastName = n.next();
    tid = n.next();
    wage=n.nextDouble();
    firstNames.add(firstName);
    lastNames.add(lastName);
    tax.add(tid);
    hw.add(wage);



  for( int i = 1; i <= firstNames.size(); i++)
  {
      System.out.println(String.format( "%03d %s" + " | " + tax.get(i-1) + " | " + hw.get(i-1), i," | "+ firstNames.get(i-1) + " " + lastNames.get(i-1))  ); 
  }
 }

}

   public ArrayList<Double> getList()
{

    return hw;
}
public ArrayList<String> getString()
{
    return firstNames;
}
}
```

Employee_Payment Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Employee_Payment {
     double hours = 0.0;
     int week = 0;
     int refer = 0;
     ArrayList<Double> hw = (new EmployeeRoster()).getList();
     ArrayList<String> firstNames = (new EmployeeRoster()).getString();


    public void payment()
    {

        System.out.println("Please enter employee ID number then week and hours worked.");
        Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
       refer = h.nextInt();
        //This was a first attempt and I know that it is really wrong
      for(int i = 0; i<hw.size(); i++)
      {

           if(refer == i)
         {
           System.out.println(firstNames.get(i));
         }
      }
    }
}
```

So I want to be able to input into the module in the second class like this:

```
     Number Week Hours
        2     1    40.0
        2     2    40.0
```

Number 2 would then refer to the second object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need all those ArrayList for what you want to achieve. You could have used a single ArrayList of Map or `EmployeeRoster`.

Now the problem with your current logic is that you do not initialize the ArrarLists in `EmployeeRoster` class when you create a new Object of it. Instead they are being initialized in another method `Roster()`. Which you are not calling anywhere in your code.

You can create a default no-args constructor in `EmployeeRoster` class that calls this method or call it using the object of `EmployeeRoster` class. Here I'll be using the second approach.

Another problem with your logic is that in `Employee_Payment` class you are initializing the `hw` and `firstNames` list with two different `EmployeeRoster` objects. You should have done this in constructor of `Employee_Payment`.

```
public class Employee_Payment {
    double hours = 0.0;
    int week = 0;
    int refer = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> hw;
    ArrayList<String> firstNames;

    public Employee_Payment(){
        EmployeeRoster roster = new EmployeeRoster();
        roster.Roster();

        hw = roster.getList();
        firstNames = roster.getString()
    }

    //....Your rest of the logic
}
```

Now `hw` and `firstNames` list will be having data and you can use them in your `pament()` method.